# Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\Desktop\FileTypes\t231214.txt'

Tags: asp.net

I am selecting a file through file upload control, after selction am clicking submit button.
In Submit button click i have a code like below.

```
System.IO.StreamReader StreamReader1 = new System.IO.StreamReader(fldUpd.PostedFile.FileName);
//fldUpd.PostedFile.FileName is C:\Users\Desktop\FileTypes\t231214.txt
string strTxt = StreamReader1.ReadLine();
```

At the first line i am getting exception like Could not find a part of the path..
This exception am getting only when i deploy it in my server.
In my system it is working fine.

Comment: where your are saving fldUpd.PostedFile ??

Answer (score 2):

The file is on clients machine on his physical location which you can not access that's why it is giving you the exception as it is trying to find the file on your hosting environment. And for your local version it is working because the hosting and machine and clients machine is same, that is why it is able to find that file. 
I am assuming you are using the `Uplaod server control` Then all you need to do is save the posted file as below,

```
   fldUpd.PostedFile.SaveAs(Path.Combine(path,fldUpd.FileName));
```

**path** Is the path where you want to save the file to.
[Here is more info on how to use the control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227669%28v=vs.140%29.aspx)

And if you directly want to read the file then you do that as below,

Direct copy from **MSDN**

---

```
void DisplayFileContents(HttpPostedFile file)
{
    System.IO.Stream myStream;
    Int32 fileLen;
    StringBuilder displayString = new StringBuilder();

    // Get the length of the file.
    fileLen = FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentLength;

    // Display the length of the file in a label.
    LengthLabel.Text = "The length of the file is " + 
                       fileLen.ToString() + " bytes.";

    // Create a byte array to hold the contents of the file.
    Byte[] Input = new Byte[fileLen];

    // Initialize the stream to read the uploaded file.
    myStream = FileUpload1.FileContent;

    // Read the file into the byte array.
    myStream.Read(Input, 0, fileLen);

    // Copy the byte array to a string.
    for (int loop1 = 0; loop1 < fileLen; loop1++)
    {
        displayString.Append(Input[loop1].ToString());
    }

    // Display the contents of the file in a 
    // textbox on the page.
    ContentsLabel.Text = "The contents of the file as bytes:";

    TextBox ContentsTextBox = new TextBox();
    ContentsTextBox.TextMode = TextBoxMode.MultiLine;
    ContentsTextBox.Height = Unit.Pixel(300);
    ContentsTextBox.Width = Unit.Pixel(400);
    ContentsTextBox.Text = displayString.ToString();

    // Add the textbox to the Controls collection
    // of the Placeholder control.
    PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(ContentsTextBox);

}
```

Then call this method as

```
   DisplayFileContents(FileUpload1.PostedFile);
```

[Here is more info on this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.fileupload.postedfile(v=vs.140).aspx).

Comment: kinda late, but this is a very big help.